# Excel formula to work out days

Tags: excel

Im trying to work out a formula in excel 2013, that will return an answer with a conditional criteria of 2 things.
In cell A1, i have a started date,
Cell B1 will either be blank or contain a completed date,
then Cell C1 is to return a number of days that is either the total number of live days to today, or to the date that is in B1?

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Kindest Regards

Isreal.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by using this formula in cell `C1`:

```
=IF(B1<>"",B1-A1,TODAY()-A1)
```

Comment: This has worked, i had forgotten that this needs to calculate working days as well (NETWORKDAYS) from A1? is that possible?

Comment: Try this version `=NETWORKDAYS(A1,IF(B1="",TODAY(),B1))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in C1

`=IF(B1="",TODAY(),B1)-A1`

format C1 as general